# "eandem esse rationem totius et partium"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In galileo's dialog of two chief world systems he reffer to an axiom

> "eandem esse rationem totius et partium"

I can't quite make out what that means, and nor can i find the axiom anywhere else, so i was hoping someone could tell me what it meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of context it could be

> "that the proportion of the whole and of its parts is the same."

That may not fit:
***Ratio*** has so many possible meanings: Ratio, proportion; Reason, principle, rationale; a reckoning, account, calculation, computation.
Link to [Perseus **Lewis & Short**](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/perseus/getobject.pl?c.16:139.LewisShort18)

Could you  provide a link to your text, please, if it's on-line.

Comment: https://svetlogike.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/4-galileo-galilei-dialogue-concerning-the-two-chief-world-systems-1632-translated-by-drake-1953-abridged-by-s-e-sciortino.pdf on page 81 in the pdf under Simp.'s line though in this version they write "tandem" instead of "eandem" which is sort of weird. Though i think you have already cleared it up for me now since he is talking about how water may not have the earths movement exactly.